# How to clear RadDataForm or individual fields in RadDataForm in NativeScript

Tags: forms, nativescript

I am attempting to clear or update the RadDataForm fields  in NativeScript after having submitted the form contents to a backend server. Unfortunately, I do not see a straightforward way to do this in the documentation or from different questions that people have asked on this site.

I have attempted to:

1) update the referenced object contents
2) update the referenced object contents and call the reload() method
3) access the EntityProperty value and modify it directly

but have had no success.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updating form by modifying the source property is still a [open feature request](https://github.com/telerik/nativescript-ui-feedback/issues/344). The workaround is to replace the source object with updated values as discussed in the same issue.

Comment: Thanks for that. I came to the same conclusion through much trial and error because my searching didn't find the feature request. I basically asked them to update their documentation because this is a fundamental issue.